# Эффективное использование Tpl.Dataflow

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl, tpl-dataflow

Задача такая: по приходу трека (их может быть тысячи) надо запрашивать данные из скробблера, обрабатывать ответ (в примере не показано ради наглядности), и записывать в файл. Решил использовать `Tpl.Dataflow` и вот что получилось:

```
static void Main()
{
    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\res.txt");

    // первый вариант
    TransformBlock<string, string> tb = new TransformBlock<string, string>(item => hc.GetStringAsync(item), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, BoundedCapacity = 200 });
    //второй вариант
    //TransformBlock<string, string> tb = new TransformBlock<string, string>(item => new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(item), new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, BoundedCapacity = 200 });
    ActionBlock<string> ab = new ActionBlock<string>(item =>
    {
        sw.WriteLine(item);
        sw.WriteLine("________________________________________________");

    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 200 });
    tb.LinkTo(ab);
    tb.Completion.ContinueWith(item => ab.Complete());
    ab.Completion.ContinueWith(item => sw.Dispose());

    Stopwatch swa = new Stopwatch();
    swa.Start();
    foreach (var item in urls)
    {
        tb.Post(item);
    }
    tb.Complete();

    ab.Completion.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(swa.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Как вы уже наверняка заметили, есть две ветки решения:

1. В первом варианте я использую **один** объект `HttpClient`, но он одновременно может послать только два запроса (кстати, почему так?), из-за чего весь процесс происходит довольно долго
   [image: вариант 1]
2. Второй вариант уже быстрее, и значительно быстрее, если распараллеливать не на 4, а на 20, например, но и тут не без минусов: создание каждого объекта `HttpClient` влечет за собой установку соединения (рукопожатие), что логично. Но как я понимаю, это лишние накладные расходы, которых можно избежать. Из чего у меня назревает вопрос:

можно ли как-то привязать один объект `HttpClient` к таску, чтоб когда он выполнил один запрос, второй запрос происходил через тот же объект `HttpClient` и не происходила установка соединения. То есть я хочу, чтоб объектов `HttpClient` было столько же, сколько `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` и каждый таск использовал объект `HttpClient`, не занятый другими тасками в данный момент. Ну или другое эффективное решение

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте пул объектов `HttpClient`. Перед запросом извлекайте объект из пула (или создавайте новый), а после запроса возвращайте в пул.

```
ConcurrentBag<HttpClient> pool = new ConcurrentBag<HttpClient>();

TransformBlock<string, string> tb = new TransformBlock<string, string>(async item => {
    HttpClient hc;
    if(!pool.TryTake(out hc)) {
        hc=new HttpClient();
    }
    try {
        return await hc.GetStringAsync(item).ConfigureAwait(false);
    } finally {
        pool.Add(hc);
    }
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, BoundedCapacity = 200 });
```

Comment: зачем конкретно в этом примере `ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: @Qutrix Код идущий после `await` (`pool.Add(hc)`) не привязан к контексту синхронизации, поэтому нет смысла это контекст синхронизации захватывать и пытаться в него вернуться, как это происходит по умолчанию.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте вместо одного TransformBlock четыре. И каждому дайте свой HttpClient.

В качестве источника используйте еще один блок.

Comment: во-первых, я уже и так распараллелил их (MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4), во-вторых 4 сложнее связывать вроде бы, в-третьих, 4 ради примера, на самом деле хорошо бы 30 минимум, в-четвертых, мне надо сохранять порядок, а в этом случае он не гарантируется

Comment: @Qutrix какая разница - 4 или 30? С порядком сложнее..

Comment: еще не сталкивался со случаем "один источник - много таргетов", Какому таргету будет передано сообщение? всем? одному? если одному, то какому?

Comment: @Qutrix одному. Какому-неизвестно (но точно не тому, который заполнен).